# Should we have monthly photo competitions?

Tags: discussion, meta, photo-competition

On many sites in the network, there are recurring photo competitions on the respective metas, which are intended as "fun" things to have on the site to get users to congregate and provide a welcome distraction. These generally run every month, with a specific theme related to the site topic that changes every month. Users submit their photos as answers to a designated question on the per-site meta, others can vote for who's submitted the best photo, and whoever has the best votes wins the virtual "prize".

For example, see the [photo competition posts on the Travel site](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition). Essentially, there's a theme for every month that's related to travel. (I happen to be running the current month's competition there.)

Should we have a similar competition series here on this site, for aerial photos taken from drones or model aircraft? I believe that this would help drive interest to the meta site and entice more users to participate in this site's curation.

Comment: Yeah. I had this idea too.

Answer (score 8):

I really like the competitions over at Travel.SE and I think this website can have the same idea for aerial pictures and related drone images.

Although it's a idea to consider in the near future our focus now is really launching the site into the public beta status.

As soon as we reach our goal, I would like this to be a reality soon.

Comment: I agree that we should have this, but I think it would be cool to extend it beyond aerial photos, for example ‘look at this wire management in my new build’ or ‘look at this custom frame I made’.

Comment: @DronesandWhatnot I can agree. I'll include this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent idea and in my opinion a great way to bring the community together.

I can volunteer to establish and run the competition if everyone is in agreement.